# How do I check case-insensitive values in Dust.js?

Tags: javascript, templates, case-insensitive, dust.js

Pardon me if this seems dumb, because it definitely looks dumb.

I'm dealing with someone else's code that essentially works like this:

```
{@select key=name}
    {@eq value="Alice"}
    {@eq value="ALICE"}
    {@eq value="alice"}
    {@any} Your name is Alice! {/any}
    {@none} Your name isn't Alice! {/none}
{/select}
```

**Is there any way to consolidate those very similar `{@eq}` statements?**

*Complications:*

- The values come in from a customer-populated database. I cannot put a cleansing step between there and the time it reaches the template.
- I can't easily add a backing helper to handle case insensitivity. It's possible, but I'm hoping the language itself has a solution first.

Comment: If you can't really touch the data itself, can you add a global helper to Dust (instead of a context helper to the data)? This isn't a super unreasonable thing for us to add to the core helpers, actually.

Comment: Indeed, I could do that! I'll probably end up going that route if there's no such core helper. I also see that the common-dustjs-helpers library has some tools that could help, too.

Comment: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers/issues/142

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion by the team the best way for you to do this seems to be to add a Dust filter rather than a helper. Something like this can be added to the dust global:

```
dust.filters.lc = function lowercaseFilter(str) {
  if (typeof str === 'string') {
    return str.toLowerCase();
  }
  return str;
};
```

Then you can do this:

```
{@eq key="{name|lc}" value="alice"}Your name is most definitely Alice.{/eq}
```